# Letter to Binary

Tags: python

I'm new to Python 2.7.10. I'm trying to convert not just letters to binary but the whole word itself.

```
a = '01100001', b = '01100010', c = '01100011'
```

If I typed "a" then it will output "01100001" but what I'm trying to do is when I typed "abcba" it should print something related to this "01100001 01100010 01100011 01100010 01100001"

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yep! And you can learn Python from the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html). Have a go at it.

Comment: `' '.join(["%08d"%int(bin(ord(c))[2:]) for c in 'abcba'])`

Comment: Sorry. My point is how to convert "abcba" to [a,b,c,b,a]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `ord` to get the ascii value of a character, `bin` to convert the number to a string of its binary representation and `join` to concatenate the output:

```
>>> myinput = "abcba"
>>> print " ".join(bin(ord(character))[2:] for character in myinput)
1100001 1100010 1100011 1100010 1100001
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(''.join(map(bin,map(ord,'day'))).replace('0b',''))
110010011000011111001
```